# How to receive data from an AJAX POST function at the server side with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I am trying to send data to the server with the Ajax POST function, and then receive it at the server side with Node.js (and then manipulate it there) but the only problem is that I am unable to find any function at the Node.js side to allow me,accomplish this.I would really like it if you guys could help me out on how to do this as even related threads, I visited on many websites were not very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: The ajax request will be made from the front end. Node.js could implement that "service" (/POST endpoint). Am I missing something here?

Comment: I don't have knowledge in node.js but is OP asking for similar thing?
$resOfTeamOne = $_POST["teamOne"];//where teamOne is name of input in front end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be much easier for you to use some Node-framework like express, to handle all that routes and requests.

You can install it and body-parser module with these commands:

```
npm install express --save
npm install body-parser --save
```

Visit express API References to find out more: http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Handle GET request to '/save'
app.get('/save', function(req, res, next){
  res.send('Some page with the form.');
});

// Handle POST request to '/save'
app.post('/save', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.json({'status' : 'ok'});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Inside your app.post() route you can get access to any post data using req.body. So your S_POST["name"] will be req.body.name in this case.

Comment: Can koa be used for this as I have heard it is better.

Comment: @TheGhostJoker yes, of course you can use Koa for this. Here is a simple example how to deal with GET and POST requests using Koa.js: http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/a-simple-crud-demo-with-koa-js

Comment: @Kevin My client has a button that sends a json message ({id: valve1, sts: 1}), but it seems never to get to the server, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

here's a simple example:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    switch(request.url){
        case '/formhandler':
            if(request.method == 'POST'){
                request.on('data', function(chunk){
                    console.log('Received a chunk of data:');
                    console.log(chunk.tostring());
                });

                request.on('end', function(){
                    response.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type' : 'text/html'});
                    response.end()
                });
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Also see [this page](http://blog.frankgrimm.net/2010/11/howto-access-http-message-body-post-data-in-node-js/).